# How make a glyphicon a button similar to twitter?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I am using materialize (www.materializecss.com) to develop and website. I am using icons (similar to glyphicons in bootstrap) to make them appear as buttons. I am unsuccessful so far.

```
Js Fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/a06n54pa/
```

[image: I want the images to appear similar to how the reply, retweet and favorite buttons of twitter.]

I want the images to appear similar to the reply, retweet and favorite buttons of twitter as shown in picture.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why `I am unsuccessful so far` , add your code here. what you have done so far?

Comment: <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href=""><i class="small material-icons">location_on</i></a>

Comment: Can you tell me what's you bootstrap version? and i no see any wrong in your code, but your icon not load for me, should test it on fiddle but need to know whats your bootstrap version?

Comment: I have added the js fiddle link. Also, I am not using bootstrap but, using materialize css. Its similar to bootstrap.

Comment: Ok I see your example fiddle, now tell me what you trying to do? sounds not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap a button with an anchor tag, or in your case your button icon.

Something like this should work.

`<button><a href="#"><i class="anyIconYourUsing"></i></a></button>`

Answer (score 0):

you are using materializecss framework which have material icon try to include glyphicons from bootstrap [customize tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) or use [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) to create custom font icon build

hope this help